# How to know the insertion/update history of one Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, history, insertion

There is one table (or called column family) in Cassandra. I want to know how many records of this table were inserted or updated since a given timestamp. How to do it?

Comment: You could add columns for created/updated timestamps.

Comment: um...yeah, but this is an existing table. And want to know the recent insertion/update history. So, add one more column is a little late now.

Comment: add new columns and use your code to update the new columns with the value of writetime of your primary key (writetime(column) function)

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to try `writetime(column_name)`. That way you will get the write times of particular columns. You won't get, however, write times of already deleted columns. It's far from what you want, but that's the only possibility.